# Java hashtable bucket as an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, bucket

I want to create a `HashMap` where each `Key` could have multiple `Value`s. For example, the `key` umbrella could have `value`s of red, black, and green. I have heard that the buckets in a `Hashtable` could be `LinkedList`s, `ArrayList`s, etc. How could I implement a bucket as an `ArrayList` so that I would be able to add items that match the `key` to the end of the list?

I want to have a something like `Map<Key, Value>`. If the `Key` exists, the `Value` will be added to the list of current `Value`s.

Comment: Are you creating your own hash table implementation or using the `HashMap` class?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If you have some code, please post it so people can help you with it.

Comment: I would prefer to use HashMap, but I do not insist on using it.

Comment: Are you looking for a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`?  You should _not_ mix up "hash table buckets" and "the values associated with a particular key."  Multiple different unrelated keys can appear in the same bucket.

Comment: I want to have a something like `Map<Key, Value>`. If the `Key` exists, the `Value` will be added to the list of current `Value`s.

Comment: If you have a `Map<Key, Value>` with multiple values, how do you expect to know which value to retrieve on a call to `get(Key)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Map<K, List<V>> map = new HashMap<>();`

Instead of `map.put(k, v)`, you will do something like this:

```
List<V> vs = map.get(k);
if (vs == null) {
    vs = new ArrayList<>();
    vs.add(v);
    map.put(k, vs);
} else {
    vs.add(v);
}
```